# Flutter Error: Unhandled Exception: NoSuchMethodError: The method 'findAncestorStateOfType' was called on null

Tags: flutter, dart

Every time I log in I get the below error.
I see there is some issue with my Navigator.pushReplacement, which gives error in the console but still allows me to Navigate.
Not sure how to fix this error.

The following code is what I am using. Please let me know if there is any I can get this error fixed.

```
class WelcomeScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _WelcomeScreenState createState() => _WelcomeScreenState();
}

class _WelcomeScreenState extends State<WelcomeScreen>
    with SingleTickerProviderStateMixin {
  startTime() async {
    var _duration = Duration(seconds: 5);
    return Timer(_duration, navigationPage);
  }

  void navigationPage() {
    Navigator.pushReplacement(
      context,
      MaterialPageRoute(
        builder: (context) => FirstTimeUserOnly(),
      ),
    );
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    startTime();
  }


  final int delayedAmount = 100;
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Center(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: <Widget>[
           Text('Welcome'),
           Logo(),         
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Here is the error I get

```
E/flutter (16323): Tried calling: findAncestorStateOfType<NavigatorState>()
E/flutter (16323): #0      Object.noSuchMethod (dart:core-patch/object_patch.dart:53:5)
E/flutter (16323): #1      Navigator.of (package:flutter/src/widgets/navigator.dart:2115:19)
E/flutter (16323): #2      Navigator.pushReplacement (package:flutter/src/widgets/navigator.dart:1781:22)
E/flutter (16323): #3      _WelcomeScreenState.navigationPage (package:/welcome_screen.dart:23:15)
E/flutter (16323): #4      _rootRun (dart:async/zone.dart:1180:38)
E/flutter (16323): #5      _CustomZone.run (dart:async/zone.dart:1077:19)
E/flutter (16323): #6      _CustomZone.runGuarded (dart:async/zone.dart:979:7)
E/flutter (16323): #7      _CustomZone.bindCallbackGuarded.<anonymous closure> (dart:async/zone.dart:1019:23)
E/flutter (16323): #8      _rootRun (dart:async/zone.dart:1184:13)
E/flutter (16323): #9      _CustomZone.run (dart:async/zone.dart:1077:19)
E/flutter (16323): #10     _CustomZone.bindCallback.<anonymous closure> (dart:async/zone.dart:1003:23)
E/flutter (16323): #11     Timer._createTimer.<anonymous closure> (dart:async-patch/timer_patch.dart:23:15)
E/flutter (16323): #12     _Timer._runTimers (dart:isolate-patch/timer_impl.dart:398:19)
E/flutter (16323): #13     _Timer._handleMessage (dart:isolate-patch/timer_impl.dart:429:5)
E/flutter (16323): #14     _RawReceivePortImpl._handleMessage (dart:isolate-patch/isolate_patch.dart:168:12)
E/flutter (16323):
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this, the timer is giving you the error

```dart
class WelcomeScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _WelcomeScreenState createState() => _WelcomeScreenState();
}

class _WelcomeScreenState extends State<WelcomeScreen>
    with SingleTickerProviderStateMixin {

  Timer _timer;
  void startTime() async{
   _timer = Timer(new Duration(seconds: 5), navigationPage);
  }

  void navigationPage() {
    Navigator.pushReplacement(
      context,
      MaterialPageRoute(
        builder: (context) => FirstTimeUserOnly(),
      ),
    );
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    startTime();
  }

@override
  void dispose() {
    super.dispose();
    _timer.cancel();
  }

  final int delayedAmount = 100;
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Center(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: <Widget>[
           Text('Welcome'),
           Logo(),         
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```